# Hide an expanded menu when clicking outside of the container: how to use code snipet

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have a menu that open a sub-menu section onclick (let's name the container: "sub-menu").
I would like "sub-menu" to disapear if the user click outside of it / on the rest of the page.

It seems to be solved on [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)
But I can't get how to use the code snipet from the second most popular answer:

```
export function hideOnClickOutside(selector) {
  const outsideClickListener = (event) => {
    const $target = $(event.target);
    if (!$target.closest(selector).length && $(selector).is(':visible')) {
        $(selector).hide();
        removeClickListener();
    }
  }

  const removeClickListener = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)
  }

  document.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener)
}
```

Could you please guide me on how to use it?

I edited, and included a basic example. -> I want sub menu to also close when clicking on the "white" space. But not on the parent "main menu" element.

```js
document.getElementById("main-menu").addEventListener("click", function() {bouttonexpand('sub-menu-class')});

  function bouttonexpand(id) {
                var elemeacacher = document.getElementsByClassName(id);

    if (elemeacacher[0].style.display != "none"){
  
       for(var y=0;y<elemeacacher.length;y++)
       elemeacacher[y].style.display = "none";
       }
       
    else {
         for(var y=0;y<elemeacacher.length;y++)
       elemeacacher[y].style.display = "block";
       }
    }
```

```css
#main-menu {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 5%;
}
#sub-menu {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div><div id="main-menu">Main menu</div></div>
<div><div id="sub-menu" class="sub-menu-class">Sub menu</div></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you remove the click listener? Also, please create a [mre].

Comment: Hi Chris, I added an example. Maybe it was not the most suited code, I am quite new to coding :)

Comment: Had to change things a bit, but here's the gist of it: https://jsfiddle.net/0j7p81sL/

Comment: Thanks ! It indeed works fine.
However I've read several time that .stopPropagation is to avoid

Comment: I've found [this article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) regarding that, and I'm not going to argue with the author about his general point, but in my view the article is more a recommendation to developers of libraries to not use .stopPropagation(). Case in point, the authors suggested way of handling this does not fix the bootstrap bug they introduce earlier. I agree that calling it in document handlers is a bad idea, but I see absolutely no issue with calling it in a single (empty) element's click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using jQuery, you can bind to the document click event and hides the div container when the clicked element isn’t the container itself or descendant of the div element.

```js
var container = $("#sub-menu");
if (!container.is(event.target) && !container.has(event.target).length) {
    container.hide();
}
```

If you want to hide that container without being tested the container itself or descendant of the div element just remove the condition and simply use `container.hide();`.

Also, rather than setting `display: none;` on `sub-menu` in the CSS, set it manually so that you can toggle the `sub-menu` from the very first click.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("sub-menu");
x.style.display = "none";

$(document).click(function (evt) {

    if ($(evt.target).is('#main-menu')) { // control click event if it's main-menu
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else {
        var container = $("#sub-menu");
        if (!container.is(event.target) && !container.has(event.target).length) { // if you don't want that remove the condition and write container.hide(); only
            container.hide();
        }
    }

});
```

```css
#main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 5%;
}

#sub-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="main-menu">Main menu</div>
<div id="sub-menu" class="sub-menu-class">Sub menu</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, it solved it ! And you're right about the display:none use.

Comment: @Naga, my pleasure.